# Compare mongoose array elements with array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

beginner at nodejs and mongoose.

I have a schema like this

```
schema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    items: [Number]
});
```

Now, i want to make a call something like

```
var myItemsArray = [10,5,23,534];
user.find({items: myItemsArray}, function(err, user){});
```

Basically, i want the call to return the user if it has any of the above items.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to make use of the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

```
user.find({items: {$in: myItemsArray}}, function(err, user){
    console.log(err, user);
});
```

Comment: Here the snippet which mentions the array comparison relevant to this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#:~:text=If%20the%20field,and%20so%20on).